# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2023

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

**Summary**: Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **October 17** to bring in 1 more moderator (to replace a moderator removed due to inactivity).

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on October 17, users can [nominate themselves](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On October 24, if there are 2 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 2 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on November 1 (or November 8, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.

Comment: Too bad I also can't join this time again... I really want to help moderating too (although I'm technically still doing that just not as moderator)

Comment: What happens if there are no candidates after 2 weeks apart from one that wants to join but isn't allowed to until february?

Comment: If there are no candidates, then the election fails. I'm assuming that if that candidate is not allowed to run until February it is because of the current restrictions around being able to run for an election, and we wouldn't lift those due to lack of candidates.